# Looking For a Simile For Something That Follows You Around

Tags: style, sentence-structure

I'm writing a blog post about the impacts of an autoimmune disease. The sentence I'm trying to construct looks like this:

"The disease importunately follows me around like a god damn..."

I'm struggling to come up with something better than "... Puppy who lost his ball."

Any suggestions? The cruder, the better. A pop culture reference would be awesome!

I'm stuck.

Comment: You already [posted this on English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/544173/283269) (where I believe it's more suitable anyway) and accepted an answer. Is there any reason you're reposting it here? Cross-posting is generally frowned upon on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Flies follow trash. Some people follow their crushes around. Stalkers (obviously) follow people around. Magnets follow other magnets. Idk

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite getting the emotional effect you're shooting for. The disease follows me around like a:

- bad memory.
- black cloud.
- stain on my soul.
- poison in my veins.
- sad, needy child demanding my attention.
- wad of gum on my shoe - always sticking, dragging me down.
- broken heart.
- note pinned to my sleeve telling me I'm different and will never be quite whole again.
- Sheldon going "Penny, Penny, Penny."
- an unhealing wound hidden under my clothing constantly oozing pus.

There's no end to the options.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could say, "The disease follows me around...

- like a moth drawn to a flame. (pretty cliche)
- like a crazy ex. (also cliche)
- like a bloodhound tracking down a stag.
- like a mosquito/Great White/vampire
  drawn to blood.
- like a curse/nightmare that reminds me everyday of my terrible luck/life.
- like the soul of a dead man who swore upon his
  deathbed that he would haunt me until I meet my demise and take my
  rightful place in the underworld." (only if you want to be *super* dramatic)

Depending on the context and if you are willing to reword the sentence a bit, you could describe the disease as a scar. Sorry, none of these are entirely crude, but I hope they at least help you come up with something far better than my tired mind could. I'll write anything else I come up with. Good luck!